# Close connection in api using jdbc template

Tags: spring-boot

I have to make REST API in spring but want to close connection, after ending of API how to. How can do that, because the connection is not closing on the database side

```
@Repository
public class ThingworxDaoImp implements ThingworxDao{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;      
    @Override
    public List<ThingworxModel> getAllList(){
        System.out.println("ThingworxDaoImp is runing");

        String Query1 ="Query.query1"

        System.out.println("MRIDUL:"+Query1);

        List<ThingworxModel> thingworxModelList = jdbcTemplate.query(Query1, new RowMapper<ThingworxModel>() {
        @Override
        public ThingworxModel mapRow(ResultSet rs , int rowNum) throws SQLException{
            ThingworxModel mThingworxModel = new ThingworxModel();
            mThingworxModel.setTotal_thing(rs.getInt("total_thing"));
            mThingworxModel.setTemplate_name(rs.getString("template_name"));
            mThingworxModel.setConnected_things(rs.getInt("connected_things"));
            mThingworxModel.setDisConnected(rs.getInt("DisConnected"));

            return mThingworxModel;

        }

    });

return thingworxModelList;

        }
```

Comment: Why you not using Spring JPA?

Comment: connections are handled according to your datasource configurations

Comment: I am new to spring boot ,can you please suggest in this code that how to close connection here, and if not than how jpa can be used to enhanced this code?

Comment: i have done the required setting in application.properties?

Comment: "the required settings". JdbcTemplate closes the connection after. But if you have a connection pool (spring uses HikariCP connection pool per default) it will return the connection to the pool and not close it and keep it active according to your settings. So please post your settings.

Comment: @Thomas by setting you mean application.properties

Comment: yes, application.properties

Comment: @Thomas here is application . properties spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://rpc1122.corp.com/O180
spring.datasource.username=mr12345
spring.datasource.password=O180dev
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop